# How to configure Jenkins "Pipeline script from SCM" with SVN

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins project, I've configured "Pipeline script from SCM" with Subversion as the SCM, a Repository URL corresponding to a repository on our test VisualSVN server (for sake of discussion, call it https://foo.bar.com/svn/Kofax/) and a Script Path of "Jenkins files/Jenkinsfile".

When I trigger a build, I get the following console output.  The repository path appears to have been improperly concatenated (e.g. it has two copies of 'svn'), but I don't know where the extraneous characters are coming from:

Started by remote host 
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: *'/svn/Kofax/!svn/bc/10/Jenkins%20files/Jenkinsfile'* path not found: 404 Not Found (https://foo.bar.com)

I've tried removing the repository name from the Repository URL, but then Jenkins says it can't connect to the repository (as you might expect).  I've also tried using an underscore rather than a space in the Script Path.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you test this with a folder without whitespaces?

Comment: Thanks Dominik.  I just tried it with an underscore rather than a space, and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the Lightweight Checkout option allowed the build to continue, so I think this might be a bug in Jenkins.

Also it appears that the repository name has to be part of the Script Path, so in my case the correct Script Path was *Kofax*/Jenkins_files/JenkinsFile.

Hope this helps some other Jenkins newbie.